# chrome shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cells' of null when trying to get the last row first cell value

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Employee Details</title>
        <style>
        table,th,tr,td{
        border: 1px solid black;
        }
        #add
        {
            padding-top:2em;
        }
        tr,td{
        border-collapse:collapse;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        function addRow(){
        var table=document.getElementById("table1");
        var x3=document.getElementById("table1").rows.length;
        var x4=document.getElementById("table1").rows[x3].cells.value;
        console.log(x4);
        var row=table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
        var x=document.getElementById("ename").value;
        var x2=document.getElementById("emp_mail").value;
        cell1.innerHTML=(x4+1);
        cell2.innerHTML=x;
        cell3.innerHTML=x2;
        }
    </script>
        <h1 align="center">EMPLOYEE DETAILS</h1>
        <div align="center">
            <table  id="table1" style="width:50%">
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>E-mail ID</th>
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td>100</td>
                    <td>Ram</td>
                    <td>ram_95@gmail.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>101</td>
                    <td>Suresh</td>
                    <td>suresh@gmail.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>102</td>
                    <td>Ramesh</td>
                    <td>hello2ramesh@gmail.com</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="add" align:left style="width:50%">
            Name&nbsp;<input type="text" id="ename" placeholder="Employee Name" required><br><br>
            E-mail<input type="email" id="emp_mail" placeholder="E-mail" required><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick=addRow()>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

> Here i'm trying to acess the value of last row first cell and increasing it by 1. and adding it to the next row but the it always shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cells' of null. 
>   The aim here is to fetch the last row first cell data and increment it by 1 and add it to the next row using the values passed by the user through the textboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays (and array like structures) in javascript are 0 based ... therefore an Array of length 1 will have a single item at index 0

Therefore, to access the last row, you would use `rows.length - 1`

also, row[n].cells has no property named `value` so I'm not sure what you're trying to access there - perhaps it's `cells[0].textContent` as a number (since you're adding one to it later on in your code) - so to coerce the textContent to a number simply use unary + - see code

you're also overusing getElementById - see code below

```js
function addRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table1"); 
  // after this, can use table instead of document.getElementById("table1")
  var x3 = table.rows.length - 1; // subtract 1, because index is 0 based
  var x4 = +table.rows[x3].cells[0].textContent; // + coerces to number
  console.log(x4);
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var x = document.getElementById("ename").value;
  var x2 = document.getElementById("emp_mail").value;
  cell1.innerHTML = (x4 + 1);
  cell2.innerHTML = x;
  cell3.innerHTML = x2;
}
```

```css
table,
th,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#add {
  padding-top: 2em;
}

tr,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center">EMPLOYEE DETAILS</h1>
<div align="center">
  <table id="table1" style="width:50%">
    <tr>
      <th>Employee ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>E-mail ID</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>Ram</td>
      <td>ram_95@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>Suresh</td>
      <td>suresh@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>102</td>
      <td>Ramesh</td>
      <td>hello2ramesh@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="add" align:left style="width:50%">
    Name&nbsp;<input type="text" id="ename" placeholder="Employee Name" required><br><br> E-mail
    <input type="email" id="emp_mail" placeholder="E-mail" required><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick=addRow()>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now this should work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that length of an array is always going to be one more than the last index, as arrays start from position 0. To fix your code, change this line:

```
var x4=document.getElementById("table1").rows[x3].cells.value;
```

Into this:

```
var x4=document.getElementById("table1").rows[x3 - 1].cells.value;
```

And your code will work.